# Cytoscape mapData in line-gradient-stop-colors

Tags: cytoscape.js

How can one get an edge color gradient that changes based on data? If I set the following style

```
'line-gradient-stop-colors':'red green'
```

I get edges which fade from red to green. If I set

```
'line-color': 'mapData(color, -1, 1, red, blue)'
```

I get edges with color based on data. But if I set

```
'line-gradient-stop-colors':'mapData(color, -1, 1, red, blue) green'
```

I get `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: _ is null`